# Deleting .Kibana results in too many redirects

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

While trying to access Kibana UI, I was getting `too many redirects`.

I checked my logs and I get this,

```
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-01-09T08:45:24Z","tags":["spaces","error"],"pid":21165,"message":"Unable to navigate to space \"default\", redirecting to Space Selector. Error: Saved object [space/default] not found"}
```

So, I googled this error and turns out it was due to the reason that I deleted the .kibana index.

then it struck me that I accidentally deleted .kibana index.

How can I get Kibana UI in the working state again?

EDIT: My kibana UI was working fine for months, but I got this problem after running curator with wrong config. So, nginx is fine.

Answer (score -1):

I got it,

I created the .kibana index manually. Here is the solution in case anybody ends up screwing kibana like me,

```
curl -XPUT -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://172.31.27.95:9200/.kibana/ -d '{ "index.mapper.dynamic": true }'
```

Comment: I think restarting Kibana would also fix this. When Kibana comes up and connects to Elasticsearch, if there is no `.kibana` index it will create one.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that at first with exactly the same logic, didn't work for some reason